# How to properly return in a switch case?

Tags: c++

Let suppose the following example:

```
int main()
{
    int value=1;
    switch( value )
    {
        case 1:
        {
            return 0;
        } break;
        default:
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Returning from a `switch` case is not structured programming, but early exit is considered by most developers as an acceptable deviation ([wiki reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit))

Most modern compilers will complain about this code because:

> 9: 'break' will never be executed

However, removing the `break` sentence will trigger the question: "Is this a fallthrough? if yes, why is the `[[fallthrough]]` attribute not specified?"

The obvious solution would be an hypothetical `[[no_fallthrough]]`, but I found nothing in that direction.

My question is:

> What is the appropriate approach in this case?
>
> - Should return inside `switch` be avoided?
> - Should `break` be kept with the warning?
> - Should `break` be removed and a comment indicating the `//[[no_fallthrough]]`?
> - Should `break` be removed and the developer notice that the `return` statement is incompatible with `break`, and cross-finger that no refactoring will break this.

Comment: Note: `return 0;` is needed. My opinion is that, `break` being useless, it is only confusing to keep it. But it is an opinion-based question ...

Comment: Which compiler gives you the warning?

Comment: *"However, removing the break sentence will trigger the question"* - In whom? A developer that only considers a line of code in isolation? Or perhaps has the short term memory of a goldfish? If the rebuttal to my question is "well, the case can be a long block", then fix *that*. Refactor the cases to be smaller and comprehensible.

Comment: IMO, you are overthinking this. Programmers are not *that* stupid, they should know that `return` ends the function, so there is no fallthrough. And it's actually more likely that they would know "`case` must end with `break` or `return`" than they would know what "fallthrough" is.

Comment: Interesting question. implicit fallthrough in a switch statement is an ancient and well known wart on C and hence C++. Maybe there should be some attribute to clarify this situation?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: clang

Comment: @AdrianMaire clang gives me no warnings https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4bKeMn

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili There's a warning option not included in -Wall nor -Wextra. I cannot remember it, but it's easy to find with -Weverything and the shown example.

Comment: @eerorika I get no warnings with -Weverything either https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EaK3o4

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Your example doesn't have a redundant `break` that would trigger the warning. See the example in OP.

Comment: @eerorika I thought OP claims that removing the break will create another warning about the missing `break;`. Okay, this question doesn't make sense then. `break` and `return` are equally good ways of breaking a `switch`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: the question is not about break vs return, but how to properly avoid warning and keeping code safe. This is not opinion based neither: what part is opinion based? If some part of the question need clarification, let me know.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I'd say all your questions about what *should* be done are opinion based and highly dependent. A matter of style. Some people keep the `break` just in case, some don't.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: No, the question is not "What do you prefer?". Keeping warnings are a bad practice (exactly like nobody would say goto is a good practice or opinion based). At some extend, even asking if Earth is spheric is opinion based (some people argues it's not), but we assume some industry standards and keeping this in mind, I see little to no place for opinion in this case: no-fall-through does not exists, break is bad practice as unused code, the return is expected to be noticed by developers. Also, I see no objections to the single answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, removing the break sentence will trigger the question: "Is this a fallthrough?

The answer to the triggered question is: No, it does not fall through because it returns out of the function and thus out of the block that is inside the function.

> Should return inside switch be avoided?

If you care about strict structured programming, then yes.

But as you quoted, most people consider it acceptable.

> Should break be kept with the warning?

I recommend against control structures that have no effect, unless there is a good argument for using it. I see no good argument for having it here.

> Should break be removed

I recommend this. A developer should be aware that `return` does not fall through as much as `break`, `continue` (if switch is inside loop), `throw` and `goto` don't.

> and cross-finger that no refactoring will break this.

In *case* of implicit fallthrough I recommend using the standard attribute [`[[fallthrough]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) if you use C++17 at least so that you don't have to rely on crossed fingers alone.
Otherwise use a warning is better than nothing.

---

Perhaps more interesting case is call to a `[[noreturn]]` function:

```
// in some header
[[noreturn]] void fun();

case N:
    fun();
     // no fall through
```

I recommend at least commenting as shown, since familiarity with every function cannot be assumed. Functions don't tend to flip between noreturn and non-noreturn, but if that happens, implicit fallthough warning covers this case too.